# push google map marker's id into array to use it later

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I have multiple markers on my google map from the database.

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map,
                            content: content,
                            icon: icon_image,
                            id:p[3] /// the is is the property id
                        });
```

I want to push them all in an array to use them on another function.

```
var allMyMarkers = []; 
  allMyMarkers.push(marker.id);
```

The thing is that this way doesn't push them all in the same array.

```
console.log(allMyMarkers);
["001"]
["002"]
["003"]
```

How can I fix this? to be ["001","002","003"]

Comment: Do you want to push the `marker` into the array or just its id?

Comment: You might want to change the title of the question then.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are initializing your array over and over again:

```
var allMyMarkers = []; //<-- override of preexisting array
allMyMarkers.push(marker.id);
console.log(allMyMarkers);
```

So first initialize your array, than add all markers and afterwards use `console.log`:

```
var allMyMarkers = [];
//start of loop
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        content: content,
        icon: icon_image,
        id:p[3] /// the is is the property id
    });
    allMyMarkers.push(marker.id);
//end of loop
console.log(allMyMarkers);
```